# What does the IMAP response "+ OK" mean?

Tags: email, imap, postfix-mta

I am working on an internal email migration tool, and I am using IMAP to copy email from one server to another. However, I have hit a bug where the server (running Postfix) seems to be responding with `+ OK` to a command and then my program hangs.

Here is the sequence of events. I try to `APPEND` a message to the new server:

```
yaWmXw APPEND INBOX (\Seen \receiptchecked \Answered) " 5-Oct-2015 22:33:11 +0000" {37020}
```

The new server doesn't understand the `\receiptchecked` flag so it objects:

```
yaWmXw BAD Error in IMAP command APPEND: Invalid system flag \RECEIPTCHECKED (0.000 + 0.000 secs).
```

I remove the offending flag and try again:

```
uoTzlA APPEND INBOX (\Seen \Answered) " 5-Oct-2015 22:33:11 +0000" {37020}
```

And then the server responds with the enigmatic `+ OK` and my program hangs. What does the `+ OK` mean? How should I handle it? I can't find any mention of it online.

In case it is relevant, here are the server's capabilities:

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is "Go ahead, send your data.", that is, the 37020 bytes your promised you were going to send.  Everything after that is just freeform text.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I guess I will talk to the author of the library I am using and see just what is going on (i.e. why it is not sending the data).